# Request-html gets data everytime function called

Tags: python

I was writing code to scrape amazon using request-html. But after writing the code I found out that request-html gets data everytime function called. Is there a way to get around this?

code:

```
class amazon:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.session = HTMLSession()
        self.r = self.session.get(self.url)
        self.r.html.render(sleep=1)
        
    def get_price(self):
        price = self.r.html.xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]', first=True).text
        return price

    def get_title(self):
        title = self.r.html.xpaht('//*[@id="productTitle"]', first=True).text
        return title

    def get_ratings(self):
        rating = self.r.html.xpath('//*[@id="acrPopover"]/span[1]/a/i[1]/span', first=True).text
        return rating

    def get_MRP(self):
        MRP = self.r.html.xpath('//*[@id="price"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span[1]', first=True).text
        return MRP

    def get_availability(self):
        availability = self.r.html.xpath('//*[@id="availability"]/span', first=True).text
        if availability == 'In stock.':
            availability = True
        else:
            availability = False
        return availability

    def get_num_of_rating(self):
        rating_num = self.r.html.xpath('//*[@id="acrCustomerReviewText"]', first=True).text
        return rating_num
```

Comment: Be more specific about your problem, try elaborating your issue.

Comment: if I call amazon(URL).get_title(), it takes few minutes to load page. Then if I call the same function a second time, it will take some more time to load the page again. I want the script to only load once for all functions.

Comment: then you can store the data and access them latter as required

Comment: But then if i=I call a function it will automatically start with executing `__init__` so will automatically reload the page. I am using classes for making the same function for multiple websites.